# Laravel redirect on decrypt fail

Tags: laravel

I'm passing an encrypted URL to my controller and I want to decrypt the URL. If the decryption fails then I want to redirect to a page and show an error message.

Currently if the decrypt fails if throw the error and dies:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
The payload is invalid.
```

How do I redirect on fail? below is the function I'm using that isn't working:

Link

```
<a href="{{ route('AdminUsers.test', encrypt("test123")) }}">test</a>
```

Which creates the URL:

```
/domain/users/test/eyJpdiI6ImFiTmZYRUY5K2ZqR0txeHNjejY2dnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicktVTWVaY0tMSXlWdEhYWjdWbWtsQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMzcxNWY3ODYyMjI5NWQ2Yjg0MzExODBhMGM4NTlmNTUwMGYwZjFiNTFjZjA2Y2VhNWUxMjBlM2I5YmMzMTY2MiIsInRhZyI6IiJ9
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/domain/users/test/{id}', 'users_test')->name('AdminUsers.test')->middleware(['auth:admin']);
```

Controller

```
public function users_test($request) {

        try {
            $decrypted = decrypt($request);
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            return redirect()->route('AdminUsers.users_overview')->with('error', 'Something went wrong!');
        }

    }
```

If I do:

```
try {
            $decrypted = decrypt($request);
            dd($decrypted);
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            return redirect()->route('AdminUsers.users_overview')->with('error', 'Something went wrong!');
        }
``
I get "test123"
```

If I change the URL to:

```
/domain/users/test/eyJXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I get:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
The payload is invalid.
```

If I add a dd($e) in the catch it doesn't run as it doesn't get to it as Lavarel throws it's error first.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGTwr.png

Comment: can you describe your error in detail? 
additionally, did you correctly import the DecryptException? 

 use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

ensure that the route 'AdminUsers.users_overview' exists  you can try a "php artisan route:list" to view availbale routes

Comment: It's not really an error as such. If I pass the function a string that has been encrypted it works fine. If I pass the function a string that has been encrpted but has been modified - it throws up the 'payload' error - which is correct as it's failing to decrypt the string but I would like to redirect on fail rather than Lavarel throwing up it's own error.

Comment: I belive if you a catching the right exception, you should be able to redirect properly, can you confirm you can dd($e) inside the catch block? additionally, can you try with a general exception also and see if you can dd() inside the catch block?

Comment: I've updated the inital query with more details.

Answer (score 0):

i just tested this with a test route

```
Route::get('test/{id}', function (Request $request, $id) {

 try {
       $decrypted = decrypt($request);
       dd($decrypted);
   } catch (Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException $e) {
       dd('i was able to see error', $e);
       return redirect()->route('AdminUsers.users_overview')->with('error', 'Something went wrong!');
   }

});
```

and it worked
my guess is that this is happening in your case because exception is being thrown by a  middleware (what do you have in your **auth:admin** middleware) or the routing layer before the hitting controller.

try with a test route please

Answer (score 0):

Your route parameter is named `id`:

```
Route::get('/domain/users/test/{id}'
```

which means your controller function expects a variable named `$id`, not `$request`.

```
public function users_test($id) {
```